# Reusing Apache Camel route and avoiding sleeping the thread

Tags: apache-camel

I am working on a project where I am using Apache Camel to establish a connection to a URL using Java code in a method:

```
 public void establishConnection()
 {
     final CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
     camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){//logic});
     camelContext.start();
     Thread.sleep(7500);
     camelContext.stop();
 }
```

The issue is that it is necessary to pause the thread, otherwise the following code executes, so to wait for the response as it takes camel time to start.

Now the issue is if this method gets called many times and I want the camel context to be initialized once only with the route so that we dont have to use the sleep here for subsequent calls.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to start and stop the context? What is the source?

Comment: But if I dont start the context, then I feel that code in the route will also not get started.

Comment: Yes, clearly the context must be started. But why not allow the context to continue to run indefinitely?

Comment: But the issue is I want to wait for the camel response when I say context to start, but it starts after some time and till then the control exits from the function and the method invoking this continues.Thats why i was using thread to sleep.But I am worried this might be a problem when many people use this.So is there a way apart from causing thread to sleep.

Comment: I'd suggest you find an example application which uses the technologies you are comfortable with and see how Camel is commonly used. Typically, your Camel route describes actions/steps, and your context remains running for the life of the application. That is, your route will be "run" many times in the same context (as starting the context is an expensive operation).
https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples#welcome-to-the-apache-camel-examples

Comment: Is it better to start the Context first and add routes and then later add the body using ProducerTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

What context are you in? You don't need to do the work to start/stop by yourself (as Adam also commented), Camel does it for you.

When you are building a Spring Boot application, check out [how to use Camel with Spring Boot](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.0.x/spring-boot.html).

When you use Camel standalone, have a look at [this example](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/camel-example-main).